# Hide Column in Datagrids which are in a TabControl / ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, database, wpf, datagrid

so i have a problem with my wpf application. I generated several tables in a local database. In my xaml code i have a TabControl with different tabs and in every tab is one datagrid. Now, I need to hide a column from every table. My first datagrid named "DataGridCPU" works fine when I write `DataGridCPU.Columns[10].Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed`. But the other Datagrids dont work with the code. I always get the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` although i know that the Column exists in my database.

```
public void showDataCpu()
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from cpuTabelle";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
            DataGridCPU.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            DataGridCPU.Columns[10].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            sqlCon.Close();
        }

public void showDataGpu()
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from gpuTabelle";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
            DataGridGPU.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            DataGridGPU.Columns[9].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
```

I tried to start the Tabcontrol on another tab so i wrote `tabcontrol.selectedIndex=1;` but it doesnt work. I am new to coding so I dont really know what to do here because in the first datagrid it works fine but in the next it doesnt...Thanks for helping me !

Comment: It does not work because the other data grids are not yet created visually. The 10th column does not exists yet, unless you click on that tab item so it gets created. Store your preferences and hide the column in other data grids through data binding and it will work.

Comment: Are you using databinding/mvvm patterns?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers. @petethepagan-gerbil I dont use databinding/mvvm patterns and I dont really know what that is all about...is it a better option to use it and easy to change?

Comment: @Alexandru Dicu thanks for the advice. I understand why it doesnt work now. But I dont know how to hide my columns through databinding. How does it work?

Comment: It's a bit too big for an SO answer/comment here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern is a nice introduction.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use that column ever, you could specify the list of columns explicitly in your SQL statement to exclude it. Or, you can remove it from the DefaultView before you populate the DataGrid:

```
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);

        dt.DefaultView.Table.Columns.RemoveAt(10);
```

If you do need to keep it around and optionally display it later, then there are two ways. One is a complete shift in how you do things (DataBinding, MVVM, etc) and the other is less work, but less pretty. It involves setting an event handler for the 'GotFocus' event of the tabItem like so:

```
        <TabItem GotFocus="TabItem_GotFocus">
```

And the C# for your Window.xaml.cs is:

```
    private void TabItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItem = sender as TabItem;
        if (tabItem == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(tabItem); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(tabItem, i);
            if (child is DataGrid dataGrid)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns[10].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

This event handler can be reused for any TabItem with a DataGrid inside; and it will affect *every* DataGrid in those TabItems it is applied to. You will need to extend it with whatever logic you've got for making those columns visible again, because it will fire every time the tab is opened.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. I need the column to display the content in a textbox and in this textbox you can type text to add content. But the user shouldnt see the column in the datagrid at all. `dt.DefaultView.Table.Columns.RemoveAt(10);` works fine too as long as the user doesnt type something in the textbox. As soon as he types something in there the column pops up again. I also tried your second solution but that changed nothing for me...